# laravel pass paginate collection to view

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-collection, laravel-views

I want to paginate all departments with corresponding companies on my view. Therfore I created the corresponding models and to select only the needed fields i created a collection. In my Controller i create an Instance of this Collection and want to pass it to my View.
Here's my Controller:

```
$deps = new App\Http\Resources\DepartmentCollection(
App\Department::where('active',1)->whereHas('company',function($query){
    $query->where('active',1);
})->with('company')->paginate(10));
```

Here's my Collection:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $arr = array();
    foreach($this as $t)
    {
        $a = array();
        $a['id'] = $t->id;
        $a['title'] = $t->title;
        $a['company_title'] = $t->company['title'];
        $a['company_id'] = $t->company['id'];
        $arr[] = $a;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

When I return the $deps in my Controller, so I can see the raw data it looks fine.

```
data: {
    0 : {   
       id : 1
       title : "Prod.asdfasdf"
       company_title : "asdf"
       company_id : 1
```

But whenever I pass the $deps to my View, i always get the complete models, as if there was never any Collection.

```
return $deps;
return view('abteilungen',['departments'=>$deps]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I tried using

```
return view('abteilungen',['departments'=>$deps->toArray($request)]);
```

but that deleted the pagination information provided by Laravel, and also the access to

```
$departments->links()
```

in my View wouldn't work.

Comment: maybe try `['departments' => $deps->toArray()]`

Comment: I editet the question, tried it as stated in the post

Comment: You gotta understand one thing, you don't have access to `links` or any other feature you have on `Collection` objects, because you are returning an array, hence the `toArray`, so do you wanna return a `Collection` or `Array`of objects?

Comment: I want to return a Collection, because I need the Pagination informations and the links

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `Eloquent Builder` and return the `Collection` with only selected columns, like this:

```
Department::where('active',1)
   ->whereHas('company',function($query){
       $query->where('active',1);
   })->with('company')
   ->select('id', 'title', 'company.id', 'company.title')
   ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that returned me an error that the company.id & company.title are not found in department table:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select 'id', 'title', 'company'.'id', 'company'.'title' from 'departments' where 'active' = 1 and exists (select * from 'companies' where 'departments'.'company_id' = 'companies'.'id' and 'active' = 1) limit 10 offset 0)`

Comment: it still returns the same error
weird, but it also says `select * from 'companies'` in the subquery, although we'd select only id & title

Comment: What about if you use `select` instead of passing array into `paginate`, try my edited answer

Comment: changed nothing, the above error still occurs
If I only select id & title, then I get a field called company but it's `null`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you need to actually select the company columns before the eagar load:

```
Department::where('active',1)
   ->whereHas('company',function($query){
       $query->where('active',1);
   })
    ->with(['company' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'title');
   }])
   ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/pagination will help you.
I did this:
`view('myview')->with('data', $eloquentData->toArray());` and everything worked fine for me.